# Toggle multiple element classes with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to toggle class when I click an element. It works fine for that element:

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA").toggleClass("classB");
});
```

But I would like to add to it to toggle classes for all elements on the page that have a particular class, say "togToo". For those elements I need to toggle between "classC" and "classD".

I'm almost certain there's a way to combine that into one click...

***^^^ UPDATED ABOVE ^^^***

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Answer Updated**

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA").toggleClass("classB");
    $('.togToo').toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
})
```

Comment: I need to toggle classes for other (secondary) elements when I click that main element only.

Answer (score 105):

If the elements to be toggled start off with one of the two classes, you can then toggle back and forth like this:

```
$('#element_to_click').click( function(){
  $('.togToo').toggleClass('classC classD');
});
```

Answer (score 14):

You can toggle N classes all at once

```
$(/* selector */).toggleClass('classA classB classC');
```

Answer (score 3):

Why won't you use jQuery class selector?

```
$('.togToo').toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".main").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("classA").toggleClass("classB");
  $(".togToo").toggleClass("classC").toggleClass("classD");
));
```

Also, when toggling classes, i would suggest having a base class, and a toggle class, instead of toggling between two classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but since jQuery v3.3, we can use an array of classes like this:

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass(['classA','classB']);
    $('.togToo').toggleClass(['classC','classD']);
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-classNames

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like

```
$(".classC").toggleClass("ClassD");
```

inside the "click" handler

Comment: Class selectors require a '.' prefix and also this doesn't toggle the classes, but their visibility, use toggleClass to toggle classes

Comment: @Koen you're absolutely right, I'm ashamed of my answer :) Fixed now

Comment: This won't work. It will simply toggle `classD` on/off for all elements that already have `classC`, without toggling `classC` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, having multiple images with class $('.img-polaroid') and class $('.drag'), when one of the images is clicked, it remove the $('.drag') to this element after having add it back to all of them

```
$('.img-polaroid').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('drag')) {
        $('.img-polaroid').addClass('drag');
        $(this).removeClass('drag');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to toggle through mutliple classes one after each other and not all together I quickly wrote a little script you can use:

https://github.com/ThibaultJanBeyer/.toggleClasses-for-jQuery

it extends a new jQuery method .toggleClasses() that does exactly what you want. check it out and feel free to make it better if you have improvements :)