# jQuery onclick issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Not sure if the `onclick` part is even working, Basically its a `.hover & .onclick` button, You can hover over it to open the menu and you can click to open and close it aswell, If its already open then it closes it.

But my code doesn't do the onclick bit. Only hovering seems to work.

```
var GN_SELECTED = 'gn-selected';
var GN_OPEN_ALL = 'gn-open-all';
var menuIcon = $("#menuicon");
var menuWrapper = $("#menuwrapper");
menuIcon.click(function() {
    menuIcon.addClass(GN_SELECTED);
    menuWrapper.addClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
});
$("#menuicon, #menuwrapper, .gn-menu, .gn-scrollbar").hover(function() {
    menuIcon.addClass(GN_SELECTED);
    menuWrapper.addClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
}, function() {
    menuIcon.removeClass(GN_SELECTED);
    menuWrapper.removeClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
});
```

If the 2 classes gn-selected and gn-open-all are applied it uses Responsive CSS to open the menu.

It works fine when hovering but not when clicking, If its already opened (From hovering over it) then clicking it should close it but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Its 3:36 am right now im tired can anyone please point out my obvious mistake?

EDIT:
I tried copying the hovers code slightly and made this:

```
var GN_SELECTED = 'gn-selected';
var GN_OPEN_ALL = 'gn-open-all';
var menuIcon = $("#menuicon");
var menuWrapper = $("#menuwrapper");

menuIcon.click(function(){
  menuIcon.addClass(GN_SELECTED);
  menuWrapper.addClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
}, function(){
  menuIcon.removeClass(GN_SELECTED);
  menuWrapper.removeClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
});

$("#menuicon, #menuwrapper, .gn-menu, .gn-scrollbar").hover(function(){
  menuIcon.addClass(GN_SELECTED);
  menuWrapper.addClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
}, function(){
  menuIcon.removeClass(GN_SELECTED);
  menuWrapper.removeClass(GN_OPEN_ALL);
});
```

But it still doesnt work properly but this time it does SOMETHING.
When you hover over it and click it hides the menu fine but reclicking it wont show the menu.

If I try click it on a phone so hover doesnt activate it doesnt do anything but if I swap the remove and add classes around so it removes the classes and then in the function() bit adds them after it works fine. Really confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to include your HTML code. It will be helpful if you can reproduce the issue by creating a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in your question.

Comment: I understand but the html is literally just a html div that has the class menuicon and menuwrapper. Its pretty basic html so I dont see it being necessary.

Comment: [Creating a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way to get an answer to your question. For example, you reference "menuicon" and "menuwrapper" as IDs in your code, but you describe them as classes in your comment. A working example will help sort that out.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant ID's. Basically its not even the HTML that has issues its the JS it just doesnt seem to do what its meant to.

Comment: I guess you are just adding class on click. But on hover its already done. You should check if exist, then remove else add. try using $().hasClass(). This might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your first code snippet, nothing in your `click` handler is set to remove the `gn-selected` class; it's just adding the class. So of course, unless you add the code to remove the class in the click handler, clicking the element won't ever remove the class.

Your second snippet is also incorrect. You can't pass two callbacks to a `click` handler. When you do that for `hover` it's actually shorthand for `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`. A `click` is a `click`, that's all there is to it. You can only pass one callback.

Your entire function can be extremely simplified with the use of `toggleClass()`. Just toggle the class on mouseenter & click, and remove it on mouseleave. This won't totally work for you because you're using other elements to trigger the states (and we don't know what this is actually supposed to look like as we don't have the html / css), but it should at least point you in the right direction:

```
$('#menuicon').on('click mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('gn-selected');
    $('#menuwrapper').toggleClass('gn-open-all');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('gn-selected');
    $('#menuwrapper').removeClass('gn-open-all');
});
```

Comment: Why in the snippet are we using Mouse enter and leave? Cant we just use click?

Comment: @ShinyMagikarp because your problem description says that you want the menu to open on hover. The click event won't open the menu on hover...

Comment: Wait so, just that snippet will do both onhover and click to open and close the menu?

Comment: @ShinyMagikarp Exactly. I wrote that to replace both your click and hover handlers. Did you check out the jsFiddle to see if it works as intended?

Comment: Yes, Didn't realize what it was actually doing having it to change the text's color isnt good for an example because it looked like the default chromes onhover thing that it does.

Comment: I just got the chance to test the code fully, The issue is that I need this to apply 2 classes not one. So I need it to apply gn-selected and gn-open-all.

Comment: @ShinyMagikarp Right. So you need to toggle 2 classes, and despite the detailed explanation and solution I provided, you unaccepted my answer because it doesn't toggle 2 classes. A quick google for [jquery toggle multiple classes](https://www.google.com.au/#q=jquery+toggle+multiple+classes) returns plenty of results that show exactly how to do this. Did you try searching before unaccepting my answer? The point of Stack Overflow is to _help_ people solve problems; we aren't here to spoon feed the exact code you need to solve your problem. If you're looking for that, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: right, But like how would I apply it to make this toggle 2 classes? The answer on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505477/toggle-multiple-element-classes-with-jquery Doesnt explain much.

Comment: Nevermind. Thank you I found it out xD Please accept my Edit to the working code :)