# Toggle and switch multiple class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add and switch classed when clicking on some cells,Like calendar schedule.

I tried sample code below,but it didn't switch each class.

My desired result is switching like below by clicking.

`null`→`classA`→`classB`→`classC`→`null`→`classA`→

my sample code is below

```
$("#our_calendar td")     
      .click(function() {  
       $(this).toggleClass('classA classB classC');
 });
```

I would like to change cell's color by creating it's css.

```
.classA {
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

.classB {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 49%,yellow 1%, rgb(0, 255, 0) 1%,rgb(0, 255, 0) 50%);
}

.classC {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 49%,yellow 1%, aqua 1%, aqua 50%);
}
```

If someone know this method,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Same Idea of [how-to-change-background-color-continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099739/how-to-change-background-color-continuously-without-refreshing-the-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below logic. Create local variable of array of classes. Use `data-class-index` attribute for td to be clicked for getting next class.

See below code

```js
$(function(){
 var classArray = ['classA','classB','classC'];
 var arrLen = classArray.length;
 $("#our_calendar td").click(function() {  
       var classIndex = $(this).data('class-index');
       $(this).removeClass(classArray[classIndex]);
       if(classIndex < (arrLen-1)) {
         classIndex++;
       }  else {
         //reset class index
         classIndex = 0;
       }
       $(this).addClass(classArray[classIndex]);
       $(this).data('class-index',classIndex);
 });
});
```

```css
.classA {
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
}

.classB {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 49%,yellow 1%, rgb(0, 255, 0) 1%,rgb(0, 255, 0) 50%);
}

.classC {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 49%,yellow 1%, aqua 1%, aqua 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="our_calendar">
 <tr><td class="classA" data-class-index="0">Date Value 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="classA" data-class-index="0">Date Value 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="classA" data-class-index="0">Date Value 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks,it seems work well!  is it possible to circulate each class? I guess if class index =4,it will be set at 0,right?

Comment: @Heisenberg I'm not the original answerer, but you can replace `classIndex++` with `classIndex = (classIndex + 1) % classArray.length;`. You can also remove the if-statement if you end up doing that

Comment: we can reset the index in else clause. Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

you have to call toggle for every class. Referred from ( [Toggle multiple element classes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505477/toggle-multiple-element-classes-with-jquery))

```
 $("#our_calendar td")    
    .click(function() {  
     $(this).toggleClass("classA").toggleClass("classB").toggleClass("classC");
 });
```

working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/mohammadyaseer/qn2m01fu/4/

Comment: this will add all classes on first click and remove all classes on second click if no class is present but it remove existing class on first click and vice versa. This will not   work for problem OP has

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar. I have created a fiddle and its working fine, please check, Thanks for your opinion

Comment: it toggles between classA and classB and not using classC at all. Check question it says classA to classB to classC to null

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your jQuery to something like below.

```
$("#our_calendar td").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("classA")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA classB");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("classB")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classB classC");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("classC")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classC");
  }
});
```

If you are looking to circulate through the classes, You can use below one

```
$("#our_calendar td").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass("classA")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classA classB");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("classB")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classB classC");
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("classC")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("classC classA");
  }
});
```